# How to get access_token for MS Graph and id_token through /authorize?p=<POLICY>

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

What I want to achieve is quite simple - let the user sign-in with Azure AD B2C Sign-In policy and acquire a `access_token` to communicate with Microsoft Graph API and a `id_token` to communicate with a private API. All this would be done in a single-page application (using ReactJS).

Perhaps there is a way to acquire `access_token` for Microsoft Graph API from an AAD B2C `id_token`? As I can without any problems retrieve the `id_token`.

I've already looked at various MS Graph scenarios, tried a sea of different variations of how I could construct the sign-in url, but always end-up missing something (`code`, `token`, `id_token`)

The App that I'm using for this was created on apps.dev.microsoft.com, but I'm not sure that it was fully configured correctly (not that there is much to configure).

And here is the output of the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={{policy}}` which indicates that it doesn't support the token as the `request_type` (if I remove the policy from the query, then it is allowed)

```json
{
  "issuer": "https:\/\/login.microsoftonline.com\/aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa\/v2.0\/",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https:\/\/login.microsoftonline.com\/{{tenant_id}}\/oauth2\/v2.0\/authorize?p={{policy}}",
  "token_endpoint": "https:\/\/login.microsoftonline.com\/{{tenant_id}}\/oauth2\/v2.0\/token?p={{policy}}",
  "end_session_endpoint": "https:\/\/login.microsoftonline.com\/{{tenant_id}}\/oauth2\/v2.0\/logout?p={{policy}}",
  "jwks_uri": "https:\/\/login.microsoftonline.com\/{{tenant_id}}\/discovery\/v2.0\/keys?p={{policy}}",
  "response_modes_supported": [
    "query",
    "fragment",
    "form_post"
  ],
  "response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "id_token",
    "code id_token"
  ],
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "pairwise"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ],
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_post"
  ],
  "claims_supported": [
    "oid",
    "sub",
    "idp",
    "tfp"
  ]
}
```

I guess what I would like to see as an answer is how can I call the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={{policy}}&...` endpoint, which would provide either `id_token` + `access_token` or code to retrieve them form the `.../oauth2/v2.0/token?p={{policy}}...`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you can get an id_token and an access_token using [OAuth2 for your own API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa), but not MS Graph.

If you have a SPA application, one workaround could be to expose your own API to the client, and that API can internally call MS Graph in application-only context. That is, it will acquire a token using application-only credentials to a given tenant in MS Graph and be able to query any user.

This can also enable you to expose a richer API (e.g. combine user attributes from the directory with application specific data), which the client applications can use for various queries and operations.

You can post a new idea or vote for an existing one (if it exists) regarding access_token to MS Graph in the [feedback forums](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, thats what we went with more or less. We created a microservice within our developed API which exposes required Microsoft Graph APIs and basically forwards the requests.